# React not rendering component in view on Rails 7

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

[Visual Studio Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT2SI.png)

This is my layout currently, if you need to copy the code please take from here:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import  * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Welcome = () => {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Hello World! Welcome to the Rails 7 Course with React JS</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Welcome />, document.getElementById('welcome'))
})

export default Welcome
```

The problem is the text in the container is not rendering in the views/home/index.html.erb where you will see `<div id="Welcome"></div>`

index.js has

```
import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
```

application.js has

```
// // Entry point for the build script in your package.json
// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
// import "./controllers"
import './react/src/index.js'
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # get 'home/index'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "home#index"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake, took some time away from coding and when I went back figured it out pretty quickly.

```
<div id="Welcome"></div> 

should be

<div id="welcome"></div>
```